# Can't generate proper anchor link in .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to create a link like `https://localhost:44332/training/course/1/buy`. Below is my code to generate it:

**.cshtml:**

```
<a asp-controller="training"
                   asp-action="course"
                   asp-route-id="1"
                   asp-route-type="buy">Buy now</a>
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Buy",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{type=buy}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

But it generates link like `https://localhost:44332/training/course/1?type=buy`

Can anyone tell me, where I made the mistake? How to generate my expected link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your custom route mapping before the default one, then replace `buy` in`{type=buy}` with other words like `{type=test}` or just use `{type}`

Final code:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Buy",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{type=test}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Comment: I did it, but it shows the same `https://localhost:44332/training/course/1?type=buy`

Comment: @Arif Do you change the order of your custom route  before the default one?

Comment: Yes. I have changed.